# Find the number of integer solutions to the equation $a+b+c+d \leq 11$ with $0 \leq a, b, c, d \leq 3$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The problem is "How many solutions to $a+b+c+d \leq 11$ with $0 \leq a,b,c,d \leq 3$.

I'm think about solving this like

$a=0$ ... $b+c+d \leq 10$

$a=1$ ... $b+c+d \leq 9$

$a=2$ ... $b+c+d \leq 8$

$a=3$ ... $b+c+d \leq 7$

But I don't know if it is correct or not since there are $3$ variables left.

Comment: Generating function: the coefficient of $x^{11}$ in the expansion of $\frac{(1+x+x^2+x^3)^4}{1-x}$.  Alternatively, apply [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) and [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: Also, as an aside, the title you chose is completely wrong for the question in the body.  We do not have to show $0\leq a,b,c,d\leq 3$ at all.  We count how many integer solutions *where* $0\leq a,b,c,d\leq 3$ there are to the given inequality.

Answer (score 2):

I think this has an easy solution.

We only cases in which $0\le a,b,c,d\le 3$, so in all a sume would done maximal $12$ and only exist one case in which we get $12$, in case in which $a=b=c=d=3$.

So we only need to count all different possibilities for $0\le a,b,c,d\le3$ and rest one case.

All possibilities for $0 \le a,b,c,d\le 3$ are $4\cdot4\cdot4c\dot4 = 256$ because each variable have exactly $4$ cases : $0$, $1$, $2$ and $3$.

Solution then is $256-1 = 255$.

We have $255$ solutions for this equation.

Comment: Why do we have to subtract 1 from 256?

Comment: Because one of all cases in which $0\leq a,b,c,d\leq 3$ is no valid.
This is in case $a=b=c=d=3$. Not is a valid case because $a+b+c+d=12>11$
Daniel

Comment: But your solution also counts a=b=c=d=1, which gives us 4 not 11

Comment: @neonpokharkar  $a = b = c = d = 1$ certainly satisfies $a + b + c + d \leq 11$.

Comment: Oh sorry, my misteka

Comment: I was also solving this, but for a+b+c+d=11

Comment: Thanks Martin Sleziak for correct my english and teach about how to enter mathematical expressions (with symbol "$")

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the dummy variable method but using the complement method (as in above answers) is preferred.

`